# Is this regulator circuit safe to use?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, linear-regulator

A friend asked me to make a simple regulator for a high current load: a 13.8+-15% V, 20 A (a radio). The input is a 13.5-16.8 V LiPo 4S pack. Obviously, the pack cannot be discharged completely. Still, a LiPo buzzer will be used to notify low charge.

I chose the components that I had available and I designed this circuit. I placed only one MOSFET, I plan to have two in parallel for better heat dissipation.

I tried to simulate it with CircuitLab, to ensure that no power-up transient would damage the radio, and the output voltage seems never to go beyond the set voltage.

Are there other potential issues in this circuit that I may have overlooked? I wouldn't like to the radio to get damaged.

For example, in CircuitLab I notice that there is a resonance at about 250 kHz where little PSRR is achieved. Can it be improved? In fact, the input voltage is very stable, only the load can be variable due to intermittent transmission. I'm not sure that frequency analysis is relevant in my case.

Edit: by using time domain analysis I noticed that this circuit is oscillating quite a lot. I guess such a simple circuit cannot be reliably used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fru5Gr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You should check the input power requirements of the radio - 13.8V is usually specified as the nominal voltage for a car 12v system which varies over the range 10.5V to 16.5V. The radio may accept that range without any regulation.  You may need a low-voltage cutoff to avoid over discharge of the battery.

Comment: 15% tolerance, I edited. For low voltage, a ready made buzzer will loudly notify the low charge.

Comment: Better to build the prototype and check for the voltage output using a multimeter. But You can determine current only when it s operated. For now, check for voltage. Current is not going to be an issue, since the radio will take the amount of current it need. Only problem is that, you may supply it with less current because of the current handling capacity of the circuit otherwise it'll be fine. Make sure to add over current protection too because you're playing with big boss(Li-po and Li-ions).